# How to get user rating programatically in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts, rating, sharepoint-api

So I have enabled Ratings in Sharepoint 2010 for a Document Library following this guide: http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2009/10/19/sharepoint-2010-what-s-new-ratings-spc09.aspx

Now I need a way to get the ratings programatically in a Webpart.

I would like a way to get a list like the following (any other way is welcome though):

```
Item Id/Url    |    Rating   |  UserId
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407954.aspx

It's funny I couldn't find it anywhere using Google, I should have search for "Sharepoint Social Rating" instead of just "rating".

Answer (score 0):

You can you [SPService](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) to Get Rating on Url:

```
        //Get Rating on Url
        //libraryUrl is url of your library
        $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetRatingOnUrl",
            url: libraryUrl,
            async: false,
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                if (Status == "success") {
                    var url = $(xData.responseXML).find("Url").text();
                    var rating = $(xData.responseXML).find("Rating").text();
                    var user = $(xData.responseXML).find("Owner").text();
                    ....
                }
            }
        });
```

When webservice return xml and then you can get some information you need like: Url, Owner, LastModifiedTime, Title and Rating

Answer (score -1):

The following is a method for getting items from a list, and displaying them in a webpart.  It uses a simple Label control, but you can format it any way you like:

```
        Dim SPListVar As SPList 'SharePoint List

    Dim SPColl As SPListItemCollection 'Define a list item Collection
    Using Site1 As New SPSite(Me.Context.Request.Url.ToString) 'Define the site
        Using Web1 As SPWeb = Site1.OpenWeb 'Define the web
            SPListVar = Web1.Lists("Tasks") 'Point to the required list
        End Using
    End Using

    SPColl = SPListVar.GetItems() ' Fill the List item collection with the return data

    Dim i As Integer

    While i < SPColl.Count

        LblRes.Text = LblRes.Text + SPColl.Item(i).Item("Title").ToString + "<BR>"

        'Read every record and put it in a new line in the Label control

        i = i + 1

    End While
```

Comment: Great, but what does that have to do with Sharepoint ratings?

Comment: ratings are just list item columns.

Comment: Yeah, thank you, but how do I get Ratings in ListItem's shape from your code? Nowhere.